# ipython problem: Tkinter GUI does not open

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tkinter

I tried to implement the following code, which should be used to get the file path of a file, using tkinter's gui:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
print (root.filename)
```

... the program runs, there are no errors, but also there is no tkinter window to chose a file.

---

I got the code from: https://pythonspot.com/tk-file-dialogs/

My operating system: Windows 10

I am using Spider from Anaconda to run the code.

---

**EDIT:**

If I change the system setting to **execute in an external system terminal** it works:

[image]

Why does it not work in an IPython 6.4.0 terminal?

---

**EDIT 2:**

Also changing the settings to **execute in dedicated console** works:

[image]

Comment: Add the line `root.mainloop()` to your code and see if the window comes up.

Comment: @ChuckG Yes ! This works ! Can you explain why ? Maybe you could add an answer such that I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter runs in a single thread, and the `.mainloop()` method starts up the thread, which is actually an infinite loop till the user/another event closes the window.

This means that if you create all the widgets that should run in your window and you do not invoke `.mainloop()`, your code will run but the window will not come up as there is no `mainloop()` to begin the root `Tk` loop.